# Existance of a matrix $B\in \mathcal M(2)$. Please suggest alternative ways.

Tags: linear-algebra

> [image]

Is there any theorem which help me to solve this question without long calculations?

---

My Try:
Let $B=
\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}
$ .The only possibilities of $A$ are $A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\text{and}\; 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1& 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

Then I Tried to solve for $B^2=A$. i got the system is inconsistent.
But this method becoming complicated for doing (b) and (c). Can you help me to do in an alternative way?

I got an alternative way to (a). $A$ is nilpotent, So, $A^2=O$. So, $B^4=O$. So, B must be Nilpotent. But $B^2=O\neq A$. Hence, There is no such $B\in \mathcal M(2)$

Answer (score 1):

First one is false,
Second and Third are true

---

**Sufficient Hint for b :**

- $A$ is symmetric  implies $A$ is (orthogonally) diagonalizable  and $A$ is positive definite implies  all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive. So there exists, $P \in O(n,\Bbb R)$ such that $PAP^{-1}=PAP^t=\text{diag}(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ where $a_i$'s are eigenvalues of $A$. From this, $A=P^t \text{diag}(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n) P$. Now set $B=P^T \text{diag}(\sqrt{a_1},\sqrt{a_2},\cdots,\sqrt{a_n})P$. Show that this $B$ works!

Use this hint to produce a suitable $B$ in the $c$ part and finish your problem!